# Ruby on Rails: NoMethodError in todos#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the NoMethodError in todos#index, and can't figure out why. Here is the code in my index.html.erb file:

```
<h1>Listing all Todos</h1>

<p>

  <%= link_to "Create a Todo", new_todo_path %>
</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= todo.name %></td>
      <td><%= todo.description %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_todo_path(todo) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', todo_path(todo) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', todo_path(todo), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

todos_controller.rb:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

  def new
    @todo = Todo.new
  end

  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
    if @todo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Todo was created successfully"
      redirect_to todo_path(@todo)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
   if @todo.update(todo_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Todo was successfully updated"
      redirect_to todo_path(@todo)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
   end
 end

    def index
      @todos = Todo.all
    end

    def destroy
      @todo.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Todo was deleted successfully"
      redirect_to todos_path
    end

  private

    def set_todo
       @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def todo_params
      params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :description)
    end
```

Comment: Can you post your `todos` controller?

Comment: Hi, I have just posted the todos_controller.rb code.

Comment: Great, thanks! I answered your question below.

Comment: Improper indentation of the code it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you had an `end` in the wrong spot. I just fixed your controller. You were ending your `class TodosController` prematurely before you defined your `index` action.

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

  def new
    @todo = Todo.new
  end

  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
    if @todo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Todo was created successfully"
      redirect_to todo_path(@todo)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @todo.update(todo_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Todo was successfully updated"
      redirect_to todo_path(@todo)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
  end

  def destroy
    @todo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Todo was deleted successfully"
    redirect_to todos_path
  end

  private

  def set_todo
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :description)
  end 
end
```